# 2 by 2 Grid of Subfigures on Beamer Latex

Tags: beamer, subfloats

I'm preparing a beamer presentation with 16:9 aspect ratio. I want to show 4 figures in one frame as a 2x2 grid. How can I adjust them on one slide. If I reduce figure size, they display far apart from each other.

This is the code that I'm using

```
\begin{figure}


\begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{\textbf{Schnitt}: $A \cup B$: Element liegt in $A$ \textbf{oder} in $B$.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{\textbf{Vereinigung}: $A \cap B$: Element liegt in $A$ \textbf{und} in $B$.}
  \end{subfigure}

  \medskip

  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{\textbf{Differenz}: $A \setminus B$: Element liegt in $A$ \textbf{nicht} in $B$. (\textit{A ohne B})}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{\textbf{Symmetrische Differenz}: $A \Delta B$: Element liegt \textbf{entweder} in $A$ oder in $B$.}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code fragments, always make a small, but compileable test document so we don't have to guess which packages etc. you use.

Comment: sorry, it was my first question here. I didn't know

Answer (score 0):

> If I reduce figure size, they display far apart from each other.

You can avoid this by using a fixed length as distance instead of `\hfill`. This way the distance between the image will remain the same when you change their size.

You could for example use `\hspace{1cm}`, `\qquad` or similar macros:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}


\begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{\textbf{Schnitt}: $A \cup B$: Element liegt in $A$ \textbf{oder} in $B$.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \qquad
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{\textbf{Vereinigung}: $A \cap B$: Element liegt in $A$ \textbf{und} in $B$.}
  \end{subfigure}

  \medskip

  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{\textbf{Differenz}: $A \setminus B$: Element liegt in $A$ \textbf{nicht} in $B$. (\textit{A ohne B})}
  \end{subfigure}
  \qquad
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{\textbf{Symmetrische Differenz}: $A \Delta B$: Element liegt \textbf{entweder} in $A$ oder in $B$.}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thank you. This is fine but if you use 16:9 aspect ratio, it gets weird.

`\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}`

Comment: @FawadKhan See my updated answer.